# SQL Start Job and transaction rollback

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, transactions, sql-job

In our database some "lazy" table updates are applied. We call an update as "lazy" when they can be executed later (not too late but not at the very time when the real and important data changed). These lazy updates usually generates and updates some report data, or updates the tables used for supporting queries.

These lazy updates usually run into deadlocks for some reasons. We tried sql locks, but none of them worked good. So we refactored the lazy updates into an SQL job, and after the real table updates we starts the SQL job to execute the additional "lazy" updates later. When another real update has already started the job, the another start cannot start another instance of the job, so no deadlock happens. The job runs until all the "lazy" updates are done, no matter who started them. So it works very well.

```
var opt = new TransactionOptions() {
      IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, 
      Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, this.TimeoutMin, 0)
};
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, opt))
{
    repo.Save(myObject)
    repo.Update(myOtherObject)
    try { repo.StartSqlJob(); } // <- might drops exception as already running
    catch (SqlException) {}     // <- in this case drop it away
    scope.Complete();
}
```

We hoped that the startSqlJob() might drop SqlException when the job is already running, we catch it and drop it away - everything good. But we detected that sometimes the code reaches the scope.Complete() point, and it says:

> TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted.
> SqlException: The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding
> BEGIN TRANSACTION.

Our idea is (not easy to reproduce this matter) that when the job start fails as the job already running - the EF call to start the job again not only fails and an exception raises, but the sql also decides that the transaction must be rolled back - and so do it! In this case the try...catch... wont protect the external transaction :(

Can it happen so? How to redesign the workflow to say that the SQL JOB START step is an optional step, and not to think its fail is important about the whole transaction state? Is it a good idea to cover this sql job start step into an embedded sql transaction to protect the external transaction against the rolling back?

Thanks for your time and suggestions in advance!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Ohh sorry to forget about it: MS SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What happens if you move `scope.Complete();` into the `try` block, so `try { repo.StartSqlJob(); scope.Complete(); }`?

Comment: As it is written: "TransactionAbortedException". The transaction is rolled back no matters of the exception handling.

Comment: The scope should be completed whenever the StartSqlJob() is success or not.